# Web scraping API that can be inserted/built in a desktop application?

Tags: web-scraping

I am working on implementing web scraping feature in a web scraping automation desktop UI application. Can Scrapy be used as API/framework and built in a desktop app for further modification or any recommendation for web scraping API that is able to be built into a desktop app?

Comment: I've seen it done with python/scrapy and TK. Kind of clumsy but a strong option.

Answer (score 1):

From your UI app, create a button click with scrappy spider call from the python script method.